# Building a particular project on svn User-wise Options in cc.net

Tags: svn, cruisecontrol.net

I want to build project when ever a user commits any change on svn. My 
project solution contains many projects as they are using some shared 
controls and functions. Now my problem is how can i build only that 
project whose user has done a commit. Is it possible to build projects 
according to users.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1):

Check [Filtered Source Control Block](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Filtered+Source+Control+Block) to see how you can filter only commits by certain users to trigger a build.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at SVN post-commit hooks - this will, at the very least, let you build your projects when a change is committed:

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch05s02.html#svn-ch-5-sect-2.1